# Ria services how to query with Nolock - Read uncommited functionality

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria

Is there a way to implement a nolock - read uncommited functionality in specific queries in RIA Services (silverlight 4)?

In Linq To Sql i can achieve the same result by setting the isolation level of the transaction to IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted.

Any way to do that in RIA?

Answer (score 0):

RIA Services doesn't query the database on its on, you have to provide it a context. If you use a LinqToSql context then you should be able to use the same methods to read uncommitted data. Just have your service context inherit from [LinqToSqlDomainService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423281%28VS.91%29.aspx).